# calculate mean of new list of number with old mean

Tags: python, statistics, mean

I have a requirement to update the existing mean when new set of data is coming.
For example,
Say I have already calculated mean of a list of numbers and kept.

```
from statistics import mean
l1=[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]
m1=mean(l1)
print(m1)
0.5
```

Then say I get a new list of numbers

```
l2=[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]
m2=mean(l2)
print(m2)
0.5909090909090909
```

Now if I take the mean of m1 & m2 w.r.t the lists separately , they are different.

```
m3=mean([m1,m2])
print(m3)
0.5454545454545454
m3=mean(l1+l2)
print(m3)
0.5588235294117647
```

So, basically, how do I calculate new correct mean m3 only by using length of l1 , m1 & l2 ? (I do not have the contents of l1 any more. But, I can get the length)

Comment: You can't, you at least need to know the length of the original list as well as its mean.

Comment: Think about it: if you only know the mean of 0.5 and you add a 1 to it the new mean could be 0.75 if the original list only contained a single 0.5, but if the original list contained a billion trillion gazillion 0.5s the new mean would basically still be 0.5 because the single 1 does simply not have a noticeable effect. The length of the original list matters to know how big of an an impact new entries can have on the computed mean.

Comment: I was thinking the same. But needed an expert confirmation :-)

Comment: Edited qn. to use length of l1

Comment: You can use: `m3 = sum([m1*len1, m2*len2]) / (len1 + len2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily if you know the length l1 and l2

```py
from statistics import mean

l1 = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]
m1 = mean(l1)
len1 = len(l1)

l2 = [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]
m2 = mean(l2)
len2 = len(l2)

m3 = (len1*m1 + len2*m2) / (len1+len2)
print(m3)
```

Output:

```
0.5588235294117647
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extend` function to add the items in `l2` to `l1` and find the mean of the updated `l1` which includes all items from `l2`.

```
l3 = l1.extend(l2)
m3 = mean(l3)
```

Comment: This is not an option as I do not have l1 any more